# Shared hashmap between threads

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a class

```
class A {
  private static HashMap hash;
  public static void setHash(HashMap hash)
  {
    this.hash=hash;
  }
  public static HashMap getHash()
  {
    return hash;
  }
}
```

I have two threads Thread A and Thread B

```
public class ThreadA implements Runnable
{
  private HashMap hash;
  public ThreadA(HashMap hash)
  {
    this.hash = hash
  }
}
```

Similarly, for ThreadB

In main class I do the following

```
main()
{
  // inserted some values in hashmap 
  Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadA(hash));
  Thread t2 = new Thread(new ThreadB(hash));
}
```

One more thread C uses the setter method for `hash` to change the hashmap. The new values are not getting reflected in the threads A and B.
What could be the problem?
Thanks!

Comment: I only see a setter in class `A`; how exactly are you changing the HashMap instance in `ThreadA` and `ThreadB`?

Comment: look at ConcurrentHashMaps for Thread safety. http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html

Answer (score 1):

Both `ThreadA` anf `ThreadB` receive a `HashMap` in their constructor, not an object of class `A`.

Even if you later change the `hash` attribute of an object of class `A`, this does not change the `HashMap` reference already received and stored by both threads.

If you want to make sure that both threads can access a new `HashMap`, either you must provide the new reference to both of them (so you need to create a setter method in `ThreadA` as well, and store somewhere a reference to the `ThreadA` object so you can later invoke the setter), or otherwise pass directly an object of class `A`.

Answer (score 0):

It's late and it's Sunday...But don't you need to be using Static classes?

I'm pretty sure that'll fix it...

Comment: Maybe some mutex locking while updating would be in place too.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437457/are-stl-map-or-hashmaps-thread-safe

Answer (score 0):

I understood your question in this way..
you have following things..

- class A {static HashMap hash, getter and setter}
- ThreadA {HashMap hash, ThreadA(HashMap hash){this.hash = hash}}
- ThreadB .. so on
- ThreadC {... some where setting hash of class A} and its not reflecting in ThreadA and ThreadB..

if this is your problem, it is because ThreadA and B already got the hash reference through the constructor and working on it, setting the hash of class A in ThreadC will not affect the already set hash of ThreadA and B.

consider you followed these steps

1. Created a hash - let assume it is referring to address 1001
2. passed to threadA and threadB so that they have hash with reference 1001
3. created another hash in threadC - let assume it is referring to 2001
4. set hash created by ThreadC to class A. ie, now class A hash have reference 2001, still ThreadA and ThreadB  hold hash with reference 1001, thats it

consider this for solution

first, in class A remove static key word and make the 'hash' instance variable instead of class variable (am not sure why you made that) and pass class A object to threadA and threadB instead of hash

- class A {HashMap hash, getter and setter}
- ThreadA {A obj,

  ThreadA(A obj)

  {this.obj = obj}..

  // access hash by using getter of classAobj.getHash() and proceed your processing with hash map

  }
- ThreadB .. so on